# Convert scala list to <repeated...>

Tags: java, arrays, list, scala, converters

I've a java method with this signature `handle(Param... params)`. How I can convert a scala list to such a sequence?

When I try with an Array, I get the following error:

```
[error]   (x$1: <repeated...>[Param])Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (Array[Param])
```

What is this `<repeated...>`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(x$1: <repeated...>[Param])Unit
```

is an internal (compiler) representation for a vararg. In plain scala this corresponds to something like:

```
(x$1: Param*) => Unit
```

In other words, you are passing a `Array[Param]` to a method expecting a (variadic) list of `Param`.
To fix this, use `_*` to expand the array and treat each element as a distinct argument. In other words turn this:

```
handle(myArray)
```

into this:

```
handle(myArray:_*)
```

See the scala specification, [4.6.3 Repeated Parameters](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters)

Comment: I can't change the method signature, it's from an API i'm using :(

Comment: I am not saying that you must change the method signature, you only need to change how you call it.